# Swift | Switch statement : wait until the case is finished before moving on to the next case

Tags: swift

I already posted this question yesterday but it had a lot of errors and that's why I'm posting it again.,

My problem is that I can't make a timer in Switch cases and each case has finished its work before moving on to the next case. If the list contains "0" and "1", what I would like to see is 1 second of white, then a black screen, then 3 seconds of white and finally a black screen.  I don't know if it's very clear but basically my problem is that Swift doesn't wait to finish a "case" of Switch before moving on to the next one. I tried several different ways but without success. I hope you will be able to help me because I can't find anything about it on the different sites I have consulted.

Signed : Valkym

The piece of code in question :

```
var liste = [”1”, ”0”, ”1”]
for i in liste {

    switch i {
        case ”0”:
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            //here wait 1 second
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            //here wait 0.5 second
        case ”1”:
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            //here wait 3 second
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            //here wait 0.5 second
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what is going to happen after the screen becomes black between the "cases". At the moment – even if you could wait – you'll never see the intermediate black screens.

Comment: @vadian Yes, you're right. There would be a half-second delay between cases to distinguish between black screens. I didn't put those in to "simplify" but I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: You can't do it with a loop and a switch statement.

This is an approach using a timer.

- The timer fires twice a second.
- The list of `0` and `1` values are mapped to time intervals (plus 1 for the black *gap*).
- A counter is set which is decremented in the action method. When the counter becomes 1 the color is set to black, when it becomes 0 the counter is set to the next value or the timer stops when the end of the list is reached.

Call `run` passing the `["1", "0", "1"]` array

```
var timer : Timer!

var intervals = [Int]()
var counter = 0
var index = 0

func startTimer() {
    guard timer == nil else { return }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerDidFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}


@objc func timerDidFire() {
    counter -= 1
    if counter == 1 {
        updateView(false)
    } else if counter == 0 {
        index += 1
        if index == intervals.count { stopTimer(); return }
        counter = intervals[index]
        updateView(true)
    }
}

func run(_ list : [String]) {
    intervals = list.map{ return Int($0)! == 1 ? 7 : 3 }
    index = 0
    counter = intervals[index]
    updateView(true)
    startTimer()
}

func updateView(_ flag : Bool) {
    view.backgroundColor = flag ? .white : .black
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works ! I just have one more quick question. How can I do if instead of 1 second and 3 seconds I want to put double values ?

Comment: You can use double values, too, but consider that there is a relation between the timer interval and the values in the list. In the given example it's 3 * 0.5 = 1.5 seconds and 7 * 0.5 = 3.5 seconds.

Comment: I tried to replace 7 by 2 and 3 by 1 but it doesn't work, any idea why it doesn't work ? Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Please understand the pattern. You want a gap of 0,5 seconds before black turns into white, so the common denominator is half a second and you have to multiply the value by 2. The formula is `value * 2 + 1`, one second is 3, two seconds is 5 and so on.

Comment: The problem didn't exactly come from there but it's all good, everything works perfectly, thank you very much for taking your time to help me ^^